# Scientific Calculator

Tags: xcode4.3

I implemented a calculator in my  app using the method below but it seems to be coming up with errors

```
- (IBAction)calculate {
    float x = ([textField1.text floatValue]);
    if (x>=)
    {
        (x<=14000,x*0.0125); 
        (x<=30000,175+x-14000*0.015);
        (x<=80000,415+x-30000*0.0175);
        (x<=300000.1290+x-80000*0.035);
        (x<=1000000,8990+x-300000*0.045);
        (x<=3000000,40490+x-1000000*0.055);
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting, the whole block looks quite ominous atm, what are you trying to achieve...

Comment: I am trying to calculate stamp duty, based on what the users input in the provided text fields

Comment: Your `if` statement is this: `if(x>=)`; that's not a valid statement, as you're using a comparison operator but only comparing one value to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here (because what you posted isn't C/C++/ObjC syntax):

```
- (IBAction)calculate {
    float x = ([textField1.text floatValue]);
    if (x <= 14000) {
        x *= 0.0125;
    } else if (x < 30000) {
        x = ((x - 14000) * 0.015) + 175;
    } else if (x < 80000) {
        x = ((x - 30000) * 0.0175) + 415;
    } else if (x < 300000) {
        x = ((x - 80000) * 0.035) + 1290;
    } else if (x < 1000000) {
        x = ((x - 300000) * 0.045) + 8990;
    } else if (x < 3000000) {
        x = ((x - 1000000) * 0.055) + 40490;
    }
}
```